# Check two location(latitude, longlatitude) near in 2000 meters

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two location latitude, long-latitude. I need to check 2nd location available within 2000 meters with first 1st location.

Also i have location array an i want to check with 1st location. I need result how many available in 2000 meters

Thanks,
Bharat Bhola

Comment: Where is the code you've tried on your own?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have started code but need know any api available for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sth like this:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

$theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);

if ($unit == "K") {
  return ($miles * 1.609344);
} else if ($unit == "N") {
  return ($miles * 0.8684);
} else {
    return $miles;
}
}
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles<br>";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers<br>"; 
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

Credits: geodatasource.com